# Typescript: issue with type intersection and type alias

Tags: typescript, typing

Using *Typescript 2.1.4*, I bumped into some weird compilation problem while using intersection types (`type1 & type2`) and type alias (`type Something<T> = ...`).

To explain what I tried to achieve: I simply wanted to declare a type alias which represents the intersection of some defined object values (in this case the property `id` of type `string`) and of custom additional properties, all of them being optional.
This type uses the *Typescript* pre-defined `Partial` type alias.

The following code compiles and works:

```
export type StoreModelPartial<T> = {id:string} & T;

function test<T>(obj:StoreModelPartial<T>) {
    console.log('TEST', obj);
}

console.log(test({
    'id':'value',
    'something':'value2'
}));
```

But when I try to use the `Partial` type alias, I get a compilation error:

```
export type StoreModelPartial<T> = Partial<{id:string} & T>;

function test<T>(obj:StoreModelPartial<T>) {
    console.log('TEST', obj);
}

console.log(test({
    'id':'value',
    'something':'value2'
}));
```

I get this error:

> Argument of type '{ 'id': string; 'something': string; }' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<{ id: string; } & T>

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah forget it, I think I figured it out by writing this question... And re-reading the error message of my code sample, which is clearer than the more complex part I was fighting with originally.

I had thought intersection and extension were somewhat the same, but nope.

What I need is `extends`:

```
export type StoreModelPartial<T extends {id?:string}> = Partial<T>;

function test<T>(obj:StoreModelPartial<T>) {
    console.log('TEST', obj);
}

console.log(test({
    'id':'value',
    'something':'value2'
}));
```